# Wireless Connections not showing up in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have just installed **windows 8.1** on my laptop but it does not showing up any **wireless connections** but when I tried to connect to my Android phone using **hotspot** it shows up that connections and easily get connected to it. I don't know the reason why it's happening I tried installing uninstalling the wireless driver from **driver manager** but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the adapter is correctly detected (driver installed), there may be a specific encryption type on your wireless. WPA2-PSK (TKIP), WPA2-PSK (AES), and WPA2-PSK (TKIP/AES) are all different options. The wrong option and you’ll have trouble detecting the wireless network.

Important note: Windows 8.1 updates remove WPA.

WPA uses TKIP encryption, WPA2 uses AES, but can also use TKIP for compatability (it can accept WPA connections).

So the best approach to this is to select a different encryption type in your laptops adapter settings. That should make the network visible.